# Call 2 functions from 2 separate contracts in one transaction

Tags: solidity, transactions, react, inheritance

Pretty standard question here I think but as a newbie I am having trouble getting my head around this in a clear way.

I am experimenting with a simple forward auction using a couple of contracts and a custom ERC-20 token, and react.js

I have an "Enter bid" button which I would like to call the transfer method from my ERC-20 Token, while at the same time calling a submitBid function from my auction contract. I can get the transfer to work no problem, or I can get the submitBid transaction to send also, but I can't do both. I think I need to inherit one contract into the other or something, but I don't quite understand inheritance fully yet.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, posting some code below:

submitBid from Auction Contract:

```
function submitBid(uint _bid) public payable {
        require(block.timestamp < auctionEndTime, "Auction has ended");
        require(_bid > highestBid, "Bid must be higher than current highest bid");

        
        currentAddressBid[msg.sender] += _bid;
        
        highestBid = _bid;
        highestBidder = msg.sender;
        
        emit HighestBidIncrease(msg.sender,_bid);
}
```

Javascript enterBid function to call the two methods, is called when user enters a bid and clicks "submit":

```js
enterBid = async() => {
    var amountToSend = this.state.bid * 1000000000000000000;


    await this.tokenInstance.methods.transfer(this.state.tokenSaleAddress, amountToSend.toString()).send({from: this.accounts[0]});
    await this.ForwardAuctionInstance.methods.submitBid(this.state.bid).call();
  }
```

My token is a standard ERC-20 token using OpenZeppelin's contracts.

Updated code:

```
contract ForwardAuction {

    IERC20 tokenAddress;

    IERC20 token = IERC20(tokenAddress);

    // Auction Parameters
    address payable public  beneficiary;
    uint auctionEndTime;
    
    // Current state of the auction
    address public highestBidder;
    uint public highestBid;
    
    mapping(address => uint) public currentAddressBid;
    
    bool ended = false;
    
    event HighestBidIncrease(address bidder, uint bid);
    event AuctionEnded(address winner, uint amount);
    
    constructor(
        uint _biddingTime,
        address payable _beneficiary,
        IERC20 _tokenAddress
        ) 
        
        { 
            beneficiary = _beneficiary;
            auctionEndTime = block.timestamp + _biddingTime;
            tokenAddress = _tokenAddress;
            
        }

    function returnHighestBid() public view returns(uint) {
        return highestBid;
    }
    

    function submitBid(uint _bid) public {
        require(block.timestamp < auctionEndTime, "Auction had ended");
        require(_bid > highestBid, "Bid must be higher than current highest bid");

        token.transfer(address(this), _bid); // This will effectively take the users tokens and send it to the contract. It requires users allowance of your token for your auction contract to be greater than '_bid'


        
        currentAddressBid[msg.sender] += _bid;
        
        highestBid = _bid;
        highestBidder = msg.sender;
        
        emit HighestBidIncrease(msg.sender,_bid);

        
    
    }
```

javascript:

```
enterBid = async() => {

    var toSend = this.state.bid * 1000000000000000000;
    await this.ForwardAuctionInstance.methods.submitBid(toSend.toString()).send({from: this.accounts[0]});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't call two separate contracts in one transaction. There's a workaround, though. I'd have the user interact only with the auction contract, and modify the submitBid function accordingly. Something like this should work

```
//This should be in the part of your code where you declare all your variables. 
IERC20 token = IERC20(yourTokenAddress);

/**
*     rest of your code
*/

// The 'payable' keyword means that this function should be called with a value transfer (= we expect the user to send ETH alongside the call). Since you're using a ERC20 token it's not necessary. 
function submitBid(uint _bid) public { 
    require(block.timestamp < auctionEndTime, "Auction has ended"); 
    require(_bid > highestBid, "Bid must be higher than current highest bid");
    token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _bid); // This will effectively take the user's tokens and send them to the contract. It requires user's allowance of your token for your auction contract to be greater than '_bid'
    currentAddressBid[msg.sender] += _bid;
    
    highestBid = _bid;
    highestBidder = msg.sender;
    
    emit HighestBidIncrease(msg.sender,_bid);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input it has definitely helped me to understand this further.
That being said, I still haven't managed to get it working! I am getting "revert -32000" error when trying to send the transaction off now.
I;m updating my code in the original post to show you

Comment: I've updated it (sorry if not clear Im struggling with this website.....) I really appreciate your help

Comment: `token.transfer(address(this), _bid);` This is transferring `_bid` from the contract to itself (which is useless and throws if the contracts balance is < `_bid`). You might wanna read  about ERC20's `transferFrom` function. Also maybe we can take this talk elsewhere if you want, feel free to drop your tg/discord/anything i can contact you on.

Comment: Oh right, of course. Sorry I had initally followed your suggestion and used transferFrom, however i tried changing it to transfer because it was giving me an error. If I use token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _bid) i get the same error....presumably for the same reason? I am off out right now but when I'm back I will post my discord!

Comment: I believe this `await this.ForwardAuctionInstance.methods.submitBid(this.state.bid).call();` was correct, why did you change it?

Comment: I changed the parameter because I was having issues before with tthe number of tokens (instead of 1 being sent it was 0.000000000000000001 etc) and I changed call to send because I figured it needs to be call because I am changing the state. I will try it again

Comment: `send` means you're sending ether (or BNB if you're on the binance smart chain etc..), so call was the right one. And yeah since solidity doesnt support decimals the base unit is 1 wei = 10^-18 tokens so you need to convert (if you wanna send 1 token you actually need to pass 10^18 as a parameter)

Comment: Ah ok, I was assuming I still need to use send because i still need to pay gas to send the transaction. I've tried it with both send and call, neither working. I get the same error but one comes as I try to send the MetaMask transaction and the other just in my console otherwise.

Comment: 1.chunk.js:85018 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Internal JSON-RPC error.
{
  "message": "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert",
  "code": -32000,
  "data": {
    "0x0792369fe15e422fa9c28a5f2e23ee736a65fc0ca833acb731f72fb691dd1f00": {
      "error": "revert",
      "program_counter": 689,
      "return": "0x"
    },

Comment: My discord is kanelawless#2409 if you are free tomorrow I would love to have a chat with you about this. Thanks again you have really been a big help to me!

Comment: sent you a friend request :)